# generating matrix with pandas

Tags: pandas, matrix, count

I want to generate a matrix using pandas for the data df with the following logic:

Group by id

Low: Mid Top: End

For day 1: Count if (If level has Mid and End and if day == 1)

For day 2: Count if (If level has Mid and End and if day == 2)

….

Begin: Mid to New

For day 1: Count if (If level has Mid and New and if day == 1)

For day 2: Count if (If level has Mid and New and if day == 2)

….

df = pd.DataFrame({'Id':[111,111,222,333,333,444,555,555,555,666,666],'Level':['End','Mid','End','End','Mid','New','End','New','Mid','New','Mid'],'day' : ['',3,'','',2,3,'',3,4,'',2]})

Id  |Level  |    day

111  |End|

111 |Mid|    3

222 |End|

333 |End|

333 |Mid|    2

444 |New|    3

555 |End|

555 |New|   3

555 |Mid|    4

666 |New|

666 |Mid|    2

**The matrix would look like this:**

Low Top day1    day2    day3    day4

Mid End 0   1   1   0

Mid New 0   1   0   1

New End 0   0   1   0

New Mid 0   0   0   1

Thank you!  Thank you!

Comment: Can you post an example of the contents of `df`? Also, it would help a lot if you added line breaks and also four spaces in front of each line of code/data.

Comment: I posted the df and line break :)

Comment: use button`{}` to format data.

Comment: I added dataframe.  hopes that would make things easier

Comment: what is the logic?Could you simplify your question?

Comment: @ErroriSalvo 
By grouping the Id together, we set out 4 paths:
Low: Mid Top: End
For day 1: Count if (If level has Mid and End and if day == 1)
For day 2: Count if (If level has Mid and End and if day == 2)
For day 3: Count if (If level has Mid and End and if day == 3)
and so on.

Low: Mid Top: New
For day 1: Count if (If level has Mid and New and if day == 1)
For day 2: Count if (If level has Mid and New and if day == 2)
For day 3: Count if (If level has Mid and New and if day == 3)...
Sorry, I know the logic is somewhat fuzzy.  I'm trying to simply the problem in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your dataframe

```
 # all the combination of Levels
level_combos=[c for c in itertools.combinations(df['Level'].unique().tolist(), 2)]
 # create output and fill with zeros
df_output=pd.DataFrame(0,index=level_combos,columns=range(4))
```

Probably is not very efficient, but it should work

```
for g in df.groupby(['Id']): # group by ID
    # combination of levels for this ID
    level_combos_this_id=[c for c in itertools.combinations(g[1]['Level'].unique().tolist(), 2)]


   # set to 1 the days present
    df_output.loc[level_combos_this_id,pd.to_numeric(g[1]['day']).dropna(inplace=True).values]=1
```

Finally rename the columns to get to the desired output

```
df_output.columns=['day'+str(i+1) for i in range(4)]
```

Comment: well, this would work if add more 'Level' and 'day' values. unclear from the question whether that was relevant

Comment: do you know why I'm keep getting
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dropna'

Comment: oops, let me fix it

Comment: the .dropna() was applied after the .values which transforms dataframe to numpy array. dropna() is a pandas function that explains the error